# iOS / Obj-C - Change request access to camera text?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I submitted my app to the Apple App Store. My app requests permission to access a user's camera roll, and in doing so presents a system generated message that says:

> "[App Name] would like to access your camera"

. That said, Apple rejected the app becaues the alert needs to state WHY access is needed and how it will be used by the app.

Having said that, how can I customize the alert message? This message is generated by the system as far as I know, as my code doesn't include it...

**ViewController.m**

```
- (IBAction)selectPhoto:(id)sender {


    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];


}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    self.imageView.image = chosenImage;

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

Comment: simply write clear message. why you need camera access ? for example, you can say that.. "app would like to access camera to upload picture"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AVFoundation Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/requesting_authorization_for_media_capture?language=objc) states that you have to add [NSCameraUsageDescription](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/plist/info/NSCameraUsageDescription) in your Info.plist and provide a clear message to explain your users why your app needs to use the camera.

This is actually mandatory and the documentation is clear about that :

> **Important**
>
> If the appropriate key is not present in your app's Info.plist file when your app requests authorization or attempts to use a capture device, the system terminates your app.

Comment: Do they provide this documentation somewhere with the Obj-c method? :/

Comment: @Brittany You don't need to write any code. Like @AnderCover said, just put the `NSCameraUsageDescription` key in your plist file and set the value to the message you want to be shown on the alert. iOS takes care of the rest.

Comment: @Pranay I updated it in info.plist, and I still get the same message I got before? "[App Name] would like to access your camera"

Comment: @Brittany weird, did you try to clean your Derived Data (⌘⇧K) ?